# Limit amount of specific div class on one page (wordpress)

Tags: html, wordpress, css, css-selectors

Is there a solution to limit the amount of div's with a particular class on a page?

I have an extension which adds `<div class="vc-box">` with content in it.

So let's say I got eight instances of `<div class="vac-box">` on one page.

Now I would like to have only three instances of that visible. The rest must be hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they all have the same parent element and if there are no other child elements in that parent element, you can use the `:nth-child(n)` selector in combination with `display: none`. To affect all children starting with the 4th, you would use `:nth-child(1n+4)` as shown below.

```css
.vac-box:nth-child(1n+4) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="vac-box">1</div>
  <div class="vac-box">2</div>
  <div class="vac-box">3</div>
  <div class="vac-box">4</div>
  <div class="vac-box">5</div>
  <div class="vac-box">6</div>
  <div class="vac-box">7</div>
  <div class="vac-box">8</div>
</div>
```

However, if those DIVs are in different parent elements or if there are other child elements between them, there is no way to do that with CSS alone - you need Javasript for that.

Answer (score 1):

You could try and use the nth-child selector to hide specific divs:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp